# OCSP resolve_blocking() and LWP::UserAgent

Tags: perl, ssl, user-agent, lwp, ocsp

This question is regarding Perl usage of 
[`IO::Socket::SSL`](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL)
/
[`Net::SSLeay`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSLeay)
/
[`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent).

To check certificate revocation status with OCSP, one needs to explicitly call the [`ocsp_resolver`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/IO-Socket-SSL/lib/IO/Socket/SSL.pod#Basic-SSL-Client) of the socket, e.g. `resolve_blocking()`.
That's the strategy I use when connecting via
[`Net::LDAP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::LDAP).

But in `LWP::UserAgent`, the connection is a private cached attribute of the object.

Can I get the socket reference from within a verify callback, i.e. the second argument of the callback?

If so then

- How? I didn't seem to find a fitting `Net::SSLeay::X509_Store<somthing>`call.
- Can I conduct blocking OCSP at that point?

If not, then

- How to invoke `ocsp_resolver`?

I need this to check the certificate status of non-stapling web servers, as well as that of chains certificate (normally not stapled).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've improved the markdown formatting in your question and removed some _fluff_. We usually keep things very professional around here and stick to only the information bits. No need to sign your post or say thank you in a question or answer. You'll be able leave comments soon, where you can express gratitude if you wish.

Comment: [Crossposted from PerlMonks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1215939).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is (currently, as of `IO::Socket::SSL` 2.056) no clean way to do is.

But since it is Perl one can do it with some monkey patching. Since the check should best be done immediately after successfully connecting to the server one can use a wrapper around `IO::Socket::SSL::connect_SSL` to get the SSL socket, do the OCSP checking and let the connect fail if the OCSP check resulted in errors:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use IO::Socket::SSL;
use LWP::UserAgent;

{
    my $old = \&IO::Socket::SSL::connect_SSL;
    no warnings 'redefine';
    *IO::Socket::SSL::connect_SSL = sub {
        my $sock = $old->(@_) or return;
        my $ocsp = $sock->ocsp_resolver;
        if (my $errors = $ocsp->resolve_blocking()) {
            warn $errors;
            close($sock);
            return;
        }
        return $sock;
    }
}

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->ssl_opts(SSL_ocsp_mode => SSL_OCSP_FULL_CHAIN|SSL_OCSP_FAIL_HARD|SSL_OCSP_NO_STAPLE);
my $resp = $ua->get('https://revoked.grc.com');
print $resp->decoded_content;
```

Note that this monkey patching is global, i.e. affects all `IO::Socket::SSL` objects and not only the one used within `LWP::UserAgent`. So it might have some unintended side effects when using in a more complex program than this example. 
A cleaner design would maybe to have some user defined callback after connect. Maybe I'll add this kind of functionality to `IO::Socket::SSL`, but for now this hack should work.

Note also that `resolve_blocking` is not using the `LWP::UserAgent` object but relies on `HTTP::Tiny`. Thus any settings specific to `LWP::UserAgent` like proxies will have no effect. If this is a problem you can do the requests manually and feed it into the OCSP resolver object using `$ocsp->requests` to get the requests and `$ocsp->add_response` to feed the response into the resolver object.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: I thought I'd experiment with letting LWP::UserAgent use an external connection cache, and deposit a verified IO::Socket::SSL connection prior to calling request().

I'll post the full example here if successful.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, I solved this by patching `IO::Socket::SSL`, to support a new `SSL_ocsp_check_callback` argument.

I evaluate it in `connect_SSL()`, right after all of the other OCSP attempts.
Here's the patch I used (over `perl-IO-Socket-SSL-2.025-1.noarch`)

```
--- /tmp/SSL.pm 2018-06-13 12:05:17.073787660 +0300
+++ /usr/local/share/perl5/IO/Socket/SSL.pm 2018-06-14 09:33:40.051022329 +0300
@@ -631,11 +631,11 @@
     my $args = @_>1 ? {@_}: $_[0]||{};

     my ($ssl,$ctx);
+    my $arg_hash = ${*$self}{'_SSL_arguments'};
     if ( ! ${*$self}{'_SSL_opening'} ) {
    # start ssl connection
    $DEBUG>=2 && DEBUG('ssl handshake not started' );
    ${*$self}{'_SSL_opening'} = 1;
-   my $arg_hash = ${*$self}{'_SSL_arguments'};

    my $fileno = ${*$self}{'_SSL_fileno'} = fileno($self);
    return $self->_internal_error("Socket has no fileno",9)
@@ -820,11 +820,22 @@
        $self->_internal_error($ocsp_result->[1],5);
        return $self->fatal_ssl_error();
    }
+
     } elsif ( $ctx->{ocsp_mode} & SSL_OCSP_MUST_STAPLE ) {
    $self->_internal_error("did not receive the required stapled OCSP response",5);
    return $self->fatal_ssl_error();
+
+    } elsif (exists $arg_hash->{SSL_ocsp_check_callback}) {
+        $DEBUG>=3 && DEBUG( "Checking OCSP with application callback" );
+        my $callback = $arg_hash->{SSL_ocsp_check_callback};
+        my $errors = &$callback($self);
+        if ($errors) {
+            $self->_internal_error($errors,5);
+            return $self->fatal_ssl_error();
+        }
     }

+
     if ( $ctx->has_session_cache
    and my $session = Net::SSLeay::get1_session($ssl)) {
    my $arg_hash = ${*$self}{'_SSL_arguments'};
```